# What should a Tree class contain?

Tags: java, binary-tree

My class is currently doing Binary Trees as part of our data structures unit. I understand that the Node class must have 3 parameters (value, left node, right node) in its constructor. As part of a requirement, we must have a Tree class. What is the purpose of a tree class? Is it for managing the entire set of Nodes? Does it simply contain the functions necessary to insert, remove and search for specific Nodes?

Thank you in advance.

My Node class:

```
class Node {
protected int data;
protected leftNode;
protected rightNode;

Node (int data, Node leftNode, Node rightNode){
this.data = data;
this.leftNode = leftNode;
this.rightNode = rightNode;
}
}
```

Comment: The use of protected variables is intentional. For the purposes of reducing the size of the post, i have removed getters and setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption is, as you suspect, a little bit flawed.  The `Node` type that you have defined is a perfectly fine instance of a binary tree.

Jack mentions that you want to have a `Tree` type around the whole set of nodes in order to provide operations like `getRoot`, inserts, deletes and so on.  This is of course not a bad idea, but it is by no means a requirement.  Many of these operations could go on `Node` itself, and you don't necessarily have to have all of these operations; for example, there are arguments both for and against having a `getRoot` operation.  An argument against it is that if you have an algorithm that at one point only needs a subtree, then the `Tree` object that holds on to the root `Node` prevents garbage collection of `Node`s that your algorithm no longer needs.

But more generally, the real question that needs to be asked here is this: which of the things you're dealing are *interface*, and which are *implementation*?  Because it's one thing if you want to expose binary trees as an interface to callers, and another if you want to provide some sort of finite map as the interface, and the binary tree is just an implementation detail.  In the former case, the client would "know" that a tree is either `null` or a `Node` with a value and branches, and would be allowed to, for example, recurse on the structure of the tree; in the latter case, all that the client would "know" is that your class supports some form of `put`, `get` and `delete` operations, but it's not allowed to rely on the fact that this is stored as a search tree.  In many variants of the latter case you indeed would use a `Tree` type as a front end to hide the nodes from the clients.  (For example, Java's built-in `java.util.TreeMap` class does this.)

So the shortest answer is, really, it depends.  The slightly longer answer is it depends on what the *contract* is between the binary tree implementation and its users; what things are the callers allowed to assume about the trees, what details of the binary tree are things that the author expects to be able to change in the future, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is supposed to give the functional interface of a Tree by [*encapsulating*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) all the behavior and algorithms related to the internal structure.

**Why this is good?**
Because you will define something that just provide some functionality and that works in a stand-alone way so that everyone should be able to use your tree class without caring about nodes, algorithms and whatever.

Ideally the class should be parametric so that you'll have `Tree<T>` and you'll be able to have generic methods for example

```
T getRoot()
```

Basically you'll have to project it so that it will allow you to

- insert values
- delete values
- search values
- visit the whole tree
- whatever

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of any data structure is to give you a way to hold onto collections of related values and manipulate them in meaningful ways.

A tree is a special kind of data structure.  It's a good choice for data that is hierarchical: those with natural parent-child relationships.  A binary tree has, at most, two children for every parent node.

One other feature of trees that deserves special mention is the fact that it's self-similar: every Node in a tree is itself the root of a sub-tree.  Recursion exploits this fact.

Yes, those are good methods to start with.  You might want to have a look at the `java.util.Map` interface for others that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, a `Tree` class should hold a reference to the root node of the tree, and to methods and attributes that operate on the tree as a whole, as opposed to methods that belong to each node, like `getLeft()`, `getValue()`.

For example, I'd define a `size` attribute in the `Tree` class, and the methods that add or remove nodes to the tree (which also happen to be in this class) would be responsible for keeping the size up to date.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it for managing the entire set of Nodes?"

Yes.

"Does it simply contain the functions necessary to insert, remove and search for specific Nodes?"

Basically, yes. For that reason, it should contain at least a reference to the root node.